# Can't sign into to Google account on WearOS emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, wear-os, google-fit

I am developing an app for WearOS using Google Fit.  In order to use Google Fit, you need to be connected to an Android phone.  So, I connected a WearOS emulator on Android Studio to my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S9+).  I am having trouble getting Google Fit code to run.  In the Log console on Studio, it tells me that Google Play services is out of date.  So, I have been trying to update Google Play services and it is much harder than I thought.  I am trying to sign into Google through the emulator itself, that way I can just update Google Play through the Play store (the other methods didn't work).  But I can't get my Google account signed in.  When I go to sign in on the emulator, it asks me to look at my phone and select an account to be copied over to the emulator.  I select my account and it tries to copy the files over.  After a few seconds, it fails and all it says is "We couldn't copy your accounts.  Make sure your phone has a network connection and is connected to your watch."  My phone has a network connection and it is connected to the watch.  Has anyone else had this problem?  I have tried the other methods that people suggest in order to update Google Play services and none of them work.  Thank you.